# Create additional View using Java LibGdx

Tags: java, gwt, view, libgdx, multiplatform

I'm doing my first game in java libgdx ( usually use SpriteKit , but I wanted to try the multi-platform ) , and I can not understand how I can go from a "view " to another. Let me explain: the default project libgdx I created the class and Class.gwt.xml Class.java .
Now , how can I create another "view " of the game ( that would be on the menu ) ?

And ' possible to create another view with its Stage and with his methods and make it appear when I press the View main break ?

Sorry if I do not put code but can not figure out what code to enter in order to do what I ask .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you called "view" is available under "Screen" in libgdx.

Since you just start, you could extend `Game` with your main core class (the class that implements `ApplicationListener` or extends `ApplicationAdapter`).

It has a `setScreen(Screen screen)` method.

Your "view" classes can then implement the `Screen` interface.

Note that libgdx is NOT a game engine, rather a game framework. This means that it provides more of a general structure for you which you don't need to follow.

This again means that it is up to you on how you implement those classes or maybe completely create your own ones. You can use the `Screen` interface, but don't need to. You can use a `Stage` (and `scene2d` for that), but you don't need to.